# Solving $3z^2 + (2+3i)z + (5i-5) = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

In a Precalculus book, Complex numbers chapter, I am given the following exercise:

> Solve the equation $3z^2 + (2+3i)z + (5i-5) = 0$, giving your answers in the form $z = a + bi$

From the way that the exercise is shown, I thought about using the quadratic formula to solve it. Starting with the discriminant, I found

$$\Delta = (2+3i)^2 - 4 \cdot 3 \cdot (5i-5) = 55-48i$$

If I could find the root of that complex number, I could finish this exercise. But how could I do that? (Wolfram gives be $8-3i$ as an answer for that root)

(by the way, this exercise comes before the root finding method for complex numbers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep it simple:
$$\underbrace{3z^2+2z-5}+(3z+5)i = \underbrace{(3z+5)(z-1)}+(3z+5)i$$
$$=(3z+5)(z-1+i)$$

so $z_1=-5/3$ and $z_2 =1-i$

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $a+bi\ne 0$.  Suppose we want to solve $(x+yi)^2 = a+bi$.

Then $(x+yi)^2 =x^2 + 2xyi -y^2 = (x^2 -y^2) + 2xyi = a+bi$.  As $a,b,x^2-y^2, 2xy\in \mathbb R$ we must have

$x^2 - y^2 =a$ and $2xy =b$.

So solve that.

$x = \frac b{2y}$ so $\frac{b^2}{4y^2} - y^2 = a$ so $y^4 +y^2a -\frac 14b^2=0$ so $y^2 = \frac {-1\pm\sqrt {1+ab}}{2}$ ad so on.

So lets solve $(x+yi)^2 =(x^2-y^2) + 2xy = 55 -48i$ so $x^2 - y^2 = 55$ and $2xy =-48$.

$y =-\frac {24}x$ so $x^2 - 24^2 \frac 1{x^2} = 55$ so $x^4 -55x^2 -24^2 = 0$

$x^2 = \frac {55 \pm \sqrt{5^2\cdot 11^2 + 4\cdot 2^2\cdot 12^2}}2=$

yea gods... calculator time ....  $x^2 = \frac {55 \pm 73}2$.  But as $x^2 > 0$ we have $x^2 = \frac {128}2 = 64$.  So $x =\pm 8$.

And $y = \mp \frac {24}8 = \mp 3$.

So the discriminate is $\pm 8 \mp 3i$.

Just like wolfram said.

Comment: The saving grace here: $5^2\dot 11^2+4\cdot 2^2\cdot 12^2=55^2+48^2=73^2.$

Comment: Indeed but... who would know and see that (if they didn't already know the answer as we did).  On the other hand aqua's clever factoring is probably best

Comment: ..... I for gosh sake.  What I normally do when trying to find a square root of a complex number is figure then norm $|55-48i|=\sqrt{55^2 + 48^2}$ but I *didn't* do that this time because want to alienate the OP with extraneous detail. Had I done that I would have gotten $|55-48i|=73$.  ... Hmm... I wonder if there is a quick way to see that if $\cos \theta + i\sin \theta = \frac {55}{73} -\frac {48}{73}$ then $\cos \frac \theta 2+ i\sin \frac \theta 2 = \frac {8}{\sqrt 73} -\frac {3}{\sqrt 73} i$.

Answer (score 2):

A square root of $55-48i$ is a complex number $a+bi$ such that $(a+bi)^2=55-48i$. In other words, $a^2+2abi-b^2=55-48i$. This is the same thing as asserting that$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a^2-b^2=55\\2ab=48(\iff ab=24).\end{array}\right.$$It is not necessarily true that there is a solution with $a,b\in\Bbb Z$, but if there is, you could start by looking for two integers $a$ and $b$ whose product is $24$. There aren't many choices. And, indeed, $8\times3=24$ and $8^2-3^2=55$. So, in fact, $8+3i$ is a square root of $55-48i$.

Comment: For pre-calculus textbook problems on topics like complex numbers, it's a pretty safe bet that the solution only involves integers...

Answer (score 1):

Use de Moivre's formula: $\Delta = 55 - 48i$ is the complex number with magnitude $\sqrt{55^2 + (-48)^2} = 73$ and whose argument $\theta$ satisfies $\cos \theta = \frac{55}{73}, \sin\theta = -\frac{48}{73}$.

Therefore, $\sqrt{\Delta}$ is the complex number with magnitude $\sqrt{73}$, and whose argument is either $\frac{1}{2} \theta$ or $\frac{1}{2} \theta + \pi$.  Now, since $\theta$ is in the fourth quadrant, if we take the choice of $\theta$ where $-\frac{\pi}{2} < \theta < 0$, then $\frac{1}{2} \theta$ is also in the fourth quadrant.  Now,
$$\cos\left(\frac{1}{2} \theta\right) = \sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos{\theta}}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{64}{73}} = \frac{8}{\sqrt{73}}$$
and
$$\sin\left(\frac{1}{2} \theta\right) = -\sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos{\theta}}{2}} = -\sqrt{\frac{9}{73}} = -\frac{3}{\sqrt{73}}.$$
Therefore, one of the square roots is $\sqrt{73} \cdot ( \cos(\theta/2) + i \sin(\theta/2) ) = 8 - 3i$.